# A probability question on $n$ occurences

Tags: probability

This is a hardware question, sorry if I fail to elaborate it in a more mathematical way.

Say, for each clock cycle, event *A*’s probability is $p(A)$. So, for a timeframe of 1000 cycles, the probability of *n* occurrences with *A* is:

$$f(n) = {1000 \choose n} \times p(a)^{n} \times (1-p(a))^{1000-n} \text{, where } 0\leq n\leq1000.$$

The probability of less than *n* occurrences in 1000 cycles is:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(n).$$

Is this correct? Are probabilities of different number of occurrences (e.g., $n$, $n-1$, $n-2$, $\ldots$) disjoint?

Comment: Probabilities are just real numbers in [0,1]. They are not disjoint nor intersect. The events are.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct, it is an example of a Binomial distribution and indeed the occurrences are exclusive f(n) means **exactly** n events.

To compute the latter sum you might use the central limit theorem to approximate the binomial distribution by a Normal distribution:

$$\mathcal{B}(n,p)\approx \mathcal{N}(np,\sqrt{np(1-p)})$$
where $n=1000$ and $p=p(a)$.